# Github Repo Protected Branch Configuration Not Working

Tags: github, merge, push, branch, protected

I am trying to configure a GitHub repo so only certain users can push to a certain branch.

The branch pattern name matches the branch I want to restrict.

Here is a screen shot of the protected branch settings:

[image]

Yet, I can still can create a pull request from any branch and merge to the protected branch.

This is an organizational repo which I have admin privileges. Can only an organization maintainer change a branch's protected settings? Is there something else that needs to be configured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is by design. The "restrict who can push to matching branches" feature limits who can *push to* a branch, but you say

> Yet, I can still can create a pull request from any branch and merge to the protected branch.

The whole point of protecting branches is to force code to go through a pull request process. Restricting push access doesn't restrict pull requests. It simply means users can't `git push` code directly to the branch.

You can also add required status checks before pull requests can be merged, e.g. for tests to pass, for a certain number of collaborators to approve the pull request, for commits to be cryptographically signed, etc.

Comment: A user can create pull requests and merge directly to the protected branch even though they shouldn't be able to. The branch also has the require status checks set as well.

Comment: Okay, but do you have any status checks configured? A CI tool, for example? Again, the push restriction doesn't affect merging by pull request. It's for pushing directly to the branch.

Comment: So Github is not configurable for restricting  which users can create a pull request to a specific branch.?

Comment: @grebwerd, that's correct. Though you can [require that pull requests be approved, even by more than one person, before they can be merged](https://help.github.com/en/articles/approving-a-pull-request-with-required-reviews). And you can [configure code owners for certain directories or types of files](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-code-owners) who can be required to approve pull requests on their owned code before it gets merged. It is this approval step, and other things like "require branch is up to date" and CI, that determine whether a PR can be merged.

Comment: Thanks for your help Chris.

Answer (score 0):

As of today (November 2023) the settings have slightly changed. Make sure to set these:
[image]
and
[image]